# Change flask.app.request_class in flask according to sending request

Tags: character-encoding, flask

From client send data(name field encoed 'euc-kr'), POST http://127.0.0.1, name=테스트&charset=euc-kr

In server(based on flask) receive data, but only Unicode and broken display.

```
@app.route('/', methods='post'):
def post():
     print request.charset #utf-8
     print request.url_charset #utf-8

     print type(request.form['name']) #unicode
```

So I use the subclass of Flask.Requsest class for supporting charset:

```
# main.py 
class EuckrRequest(Request):
    url_charset = 'euc-kr'
    charset = 'euc-kr'

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='', static_folder='static')
app.request_class=EuckrRequest
```

So good and not broken display. But I want to change `app.request_class` according to `charset` in POST data.

How to modify code? app.request_context?, app.before_request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dynamically changing the request class is the wrong way to go about this,
since the request class is instantiated very early to begin with

i suggest you reach in to `request.environ` and handle the details explicitly from the data that came in

Comment: Could I use request.environ[''werkzeug.request']?

Comment: It is possible using werkzeug.contrib.wrappers.DynamicCharsetRequestMixin?

Comment: that one is agood find, i think a custom Request, that uses that mixin as first base class could help you,\

in any case, the mixin can also serve as example on how to make a better suited class

Answer (score 0):

I solve use `request.get_data()`

```
   import urllib
   urllib.unquote(request.get_data()).decode('euc-kr')
```